# preg_match - text between closing and opening tag

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, preg-match

I've very odd task to do.

I need to grab text from html tags using preg_match() function in PHP. Problem is that text I need is between closing and opening html tags or this text with tags.

Below is my html string:

```
<h2>Title of post</h2> 1 category <strong>task 1</strong> 1 category <strong>task 2</strong> 1 category <strong>task 3</strong>&nbsp;
```

To be more specific: I need string " 1 category " between `</h2>` and `<strong>` tag.

When i try to grab text between opening and closing tags - It's working fine and I'm using this function:

```
preg_match_all('#<strong>(.*?)</strong>#',$string,$matches);
```

I've tried many combinations to get text between closing and opening tags. None of them worked out. I've ended using function like this:

```
preg_match_all('#<\/strong>(.*?)<strong>#',$content,$matches_all);
```

With no results.

The strange thins is that on online regex testers this function with above pattern with above function works sometimes.

Do I have bad pattern? Am I missing some flags? Do you know what can be best way to get text in this way? Unfortunately I have to do with Regex approach, the solutions like XMLDomParser is not allowed in my case.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Why you said it didn't work for you? Input? Output? Expected output?

Comment: You may prepare some code at http://ideone.com or similar

Comment: You can split the string into an array by your first working regex. The resulting array will have `" 1 category "`. Something like `$arr = preg_split("/<(strong|h2)>.*?</(\1)>/", $input);`

Comment: You can try these links: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ITOQyX/1), [ideone](https://ideone.com/QXBklG#stdin). Both with a working example.

Comment: @fabtosz please explain why you are not allowed to use an appropriate tool for this task.  https://3v4l.org/5BIG4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something wrong with your php installation/configuration.

Your code as it's.

```
$content = '<h2>Title of post</h2> 1 category <strong>task 1</strong> 1 category <strong>task 2</strong> 1 category <strong>task 3</strong>&nbsp;'; 
preg_match_all('#<\/h2>(.*?)<strong>#',$content,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => </h2> 1 category <strong>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  1 category 
        )

)
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/3lUoe)

**Note**: Since there is only one match of your pattern ( between `</h2>` `<strong>`) you can access like `$maches[1][0]` or use `preg_match`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
preg_match_all('/<([^>]+)>(?:([^<]+))*(?=[^>]*\<)/',$string,$matches);
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7bKF4/1)

Comment: _Try this_ answers do very little to educate the OP and future researchers.  Please always, always include some kind of explanation with every answer that you post with the intention to educate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **all** pieces of text between a closing and opening tag, you could use this code. Note that I changed your text so that the text between each set of closing/opening tags was different so that it was more obvious that the match was finding each value.

```
$str = '<h2>Title of post</h2> 1 category <strong>task 1</strong> 2 category <strong>task 2</strong> 3 category <strong>task 3</strong> ';
preg_match_all('#(?:</[^>]+>)(.*?)<#', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  1 category 
    [1] =>  2 category 
    [2] =>  3 category 
)
```